# Taking a snapshot from the command prompt for Hyper-V 2008

Tags: windows, snapshot, hyper-v

Background:
I am using Hyper-V on Server 2008 to manage many virtual servers.   I have scripts that have been built to make changes or apply updates to some or all of these virtual servers.  Using the Hyper-V Manager, I am able to snapshot these virtual servers prior to doing an update, then roll back the changes if there is a problem.

The Question:
What I would like to do is script from a batch file or something similar this whole process of the snapshot on Hyper-V on Microsoft Windows Server 2008.  How can you trigger a snapshot from the windows command prompt in Hyper-V?

Thanks in advance for any hep with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it with [powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/jamesone/archive/2008/05/02/hyper-v-and-snapshots-part-1.aspx)